# Is it possible to allow multiple testenv labels with the same script?

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, tox

Currently we have multiple `toxenv` that's just a simple copy+paste code:

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/alvations-test-tox/tox.ini

```
[testenv:py2.7.14-jenkins]
basepython = python
commands = {toxinidir}/jenkins.sh
setenv =
    STANFORD_MODELS = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_PARSER = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_POSTAGGER = {homedir}/third/stanford-postagger/


[testenv:py3.5.4-jenkins]
basepython = python3
commands = {toxinidir}/jenkins.sh
setenv =
    STANFORD_MODELS = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_PARSER = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_POSTAGGER = {homedir}/third/stanford-postagger/

[testenv:py3.6.4-jenkins]
basepython = python3
commands = {toxinidir}/jenkins.sh
setenv =
    STANFORD_MODELS = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_PARSER = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_POSTAGGER = {homedir}/third/stanford-postagger/
```

**Is there someway to assign multiple label to the same `toxenv`?**

E.g.

```
[testenv:py3.6.4-jenkins,py3.5.4-jenkins,py3-jenkins]
basepython = python3
commands = {toxinidir}/jenkins.sh
setenv =
    STANFORD_MODELS = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_PARSER = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_POSTAGGER = {homedir}/third/stanford-postagger/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can refactor your `tox.ini` the following way:

```
[testenv]
commands = {toxinidir}/jenkins.sh
setenv =
    STANFORD_MODELS = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_PARSER = {homedir}/third/stanford-parser/
    STANFORD_POSTAGGER = {homedir}/third/stanford-postagger/

[testenv:py2.7.4-jenkins]
basepython = python

[testenv:py3-jenkins]
basepython = python3

[testenv:py3.5.4-jenkins]
basepython = {[testenv:py3-jenkins]basepython}

[testenv:py3.6.4-jenkins]
basepython = {[testenv:py3-jenkins]basepython}
```

`[testenv]` defines variables common to all sections.

Comment: Quick question, can you "inherit" from a other environment that's not `testenv`? E.g. `[testenv:py27-jenkins]` and then `[py27-jenkins:py2.7.14-jenkins]`

Comment: "Inheritance" from `[testenv]` is automatic, at provides default values for all other test envs. All other sections you have to name explicitly but yes, that's possible. For example, [in this tox.ini](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/django-cheetahtemplate/blob/master/tox.ini) I defined section `[tests]` and use `{[tests]commands}` in all other envs.

Comment: Thanks! The example tox.ini is exactly the thing I'm looking for!